# React Native: How to export an array of data such that it can be used in multiple components?

Tags: react-native

Sorry, I'm new to React Native. I have an array like this:

```
const movementCode = {
  '0': I18n.t('$reports_unknown'),
  '1': I18n.t('$reports_movements_inbed'),
  '2': I18n.t('$reports_movements_offbed'),
  '3': I18n.t('$reports_movements_inchair'), 
  ...
}
```

I want to use this array of data in several components in my React Native project. instead of copying and pasting this array to multiple components, how can I create a file to export this data and just import and use the array?

Thank you,
Sorry if this is not a smart question

Answer (score 0):

Use `export` to reuse code across the files.

```
export default {
  '0': I18n.t('$reports_unknown'),
  '1': I18n.t('$reports_movements_inbed'),
  '2': I18n.t('$reports_movements_offbed'),
  '3': I18n.t('$reports_movements_inchair'), 
}
```

You can use it in any javascript file by `import`

```
import movementCodes from 'path/to/movementCodes.js'

Object.entries(movementCodes).forEach(([key, value]) => {
   console.log(`${key} ${value}`); 
})
```

When you have only single function/variable to export use `default`.

You can export multiple functions/variables like this.

```
// file1.js
export const month = "june"
export const year = 2018
```

Now you can import them as follows:

```
import {month, year} from 'path/to/file1.js'
```